# call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in Laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel-4

This question might already exist but it seems like I can't pull it off. I keep getting this error.
I am building a REST using laravel

model class Token

```
class Token extends Eloquent{
        protected $table = 'tokens';
        protected $fillable = ['api_token', 'client', 'user_id', 'expires_on'];
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
        }
}
```

model class User

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function tokens(){
        return $this->hasMany('Token');
    }
}
```

filters.php

```
Route::filter('auth.token', function(){
    $api_token = Input::get('token');
    $token = Token::where('api_token',$api_token)->first();
    if($token){
        $id=  $token->user_id;
        Auth::loginUsingId($id);
    } else {
        return Response::json(['message'=>'Anauthorized Code']);
    }
});
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'v1/'), function(){
        Route::get('/', ['before'=>'auth.token'], function(){
            return "valid";
        });
});
```

It seems like the error is on this line `Auth::loginUsingId($id);`.
I've also the code below and I got this exception same exception

```
$user = User::find($token->user_id);
Auth::login($user);
```

can anyone help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any indication of which `call_user_func_array` is throwing your error? You should get a line number?

Comment: I've already tried that. and I get the same error. I'm sure that it pass after the if condition as I've tried to return the token and it's fine.

Comment: There is no line number in the exception. and also It's working fine when I remove `Auth::login($user);`.

Comment: It's working find when I add return; Auth::loginUsingId($token->user_id) but I don't need to this return. how can I work around with this one?